# How would you simplify this piece of code using lambda?

Tags: typescript, lambda

I am learning lambda. Tell me how you can simplify this expression? I only had enough for a map, thanks!

```
            array.map(value => {
                if (value.id !== 1) {
                    value.id -= 1;
                }
            });
```

Comment: According to your `lambda` tag, lambdas are "anonymous functions or closures". You are already passing an anonymous function to `map`, so I guess you did it? Can you explain a bit more about what your goal is?

Comment: @AlexWayne I thought somehow it is possible to simplify the expression with if, something like a filter and combine it with a map

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor into a [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do the `id` check and a [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to do the `id` modification, like this:

```
array.filter(v => v.id !== 1).forEach(v => v.id--);
```

I'm not sure if that really counts as "simplifying"; all it does is turn a single method calling a two-step callback into two methods that each call a one-step callback. I'd say it's a matter of opinion which version, if any, is simpler.

---

In either case, though, you probably want to be using `forEach()` instead of [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).  They are similar, but `map()` produces a new array composed of the return values of the callback for each element of the original array, whereas `forEach()` just calls the callback and does not return anything.  Since you don't seem to care about the callback's return values and you don't save the results of `array.map()` somewhere, I'd suggest `forEach()`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAnjAvDA2gbxgSwBMAuGARgAYYBfAGhjyNIGYb7GTyaBdAKF8TIUAOgBm+ADZQApggAUANwwA+GAuFEYAQnSYyASjEgEAUTjAAFopVqNhALT39Abn6hIICdOESQAczlBVBcYAHpQ7BwmGABOOgZogCZ4qM4yaj5eGCA)